# Матрица проекции работает не корректно

Tags: графика, vulkan

[image: Камера смотрит сверху вниз]
Камера смотрит сверху вниз, чем дальше точки, тем шире, а должно быть наоборот, матрица выглядит примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Откуда вы эту матрицу взяли, как получили? И совет - для отладки лучше рисуйте единичный куб или единичные оси.

Comment: @Kromster `Matrix4X4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathF.PI/4, (float)pickedExtent.Width / (float)pickedExtent.Height, 0.1f, 100.0f);` из библиотеки метод, матрица выглядит некорректной потому что судя по туториалам в ячейке 34 должна положительная едицина точно, мейби она как-то "инвертирована" или еще что-то

Comment: В целом нормально выглядит - https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/120338